# Npgsql design time support in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, postgresql, design-time, npgsql, gacutil

How to enable Npgsql design time support in Visual Studio 2008? I did exactly what [manual](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html) says:
1) I have Npgsql.dll installed in c:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\Npgsql\ms.net3.5sp1\
2) cd into that dir and run

```
gacutil -i Npgsql.dll
```

3) Added a new Registry-Key called "Npgsql" below 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders' and set its default value to the path of my Npgsql.dll, point 1.

However still do not see PostgreSQL provider in Data Connection/Server Explorer. What I've mised or did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the current design time support of Npgsql only works on VS.net 2010 :(

And it is in a very alpha shape.

We are working to get it working on other versions.

This Npgsql.VisualStudio.dll is a very early attempt to create a design time support but it doesn't work.

Sorry for that :(

Comment: How close is it now? Is this supported in 2.0.12.0?

Comment: Unfortunately we couldn't make it to 2.0.12. We have a Pull request on github with initial support: https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/pull/98 Please, have a look and let us know what you think.